# GluonFX Gradle plugin NativeRunAgentTask sets an invalid path for the java executable

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, graalvm-native-image, gluonfx

I'm trying to create a native image of my JavaFX application via the [GluonFX Gradle plugin](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluonfx-gradle-plugin).
When I try to run the `nativeRunAgent` task, I get this failure message:

```
RunAgent failure: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: The configured executable does not exist (<path to my GraalVM JDK installation>\bin\java)
```

After digging with a debugger for a bit, I found that the `executable` property in `org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultProcessForkOptions` is overwritten several times throughout execution with paths to the java executables of different JDKs on my system.
All of these paths end in `\bin\java.exe`, except for the one set by `com.gluonhq.gradle.tasks.NativeRunAgentTask.action()`, which just ends in `\bin\java`. This happens in the following line:

```
// set java_home
execTask.executable(Path.of(graalVMHome.toString(), "bin", "java").toString());
```

This seems to be causing the Exception down the road since the path is not pointing to the `java.exe` file.

Is this a bug in the GluonFX plugin or did I miss something?

Comment: Probably better to file an issue https://github.com/gluonhq/gluonfx-gradle-plugin/issues. (The GluonFX Maven plugin does the same, so feel free to file it there too https://github.com/gluonhq/gluonfx-maven-plugin/issues)